# in app purchases on iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Hi I want to implement an in app purchase for my app but the problem is that the product would not be automatically delivered it would take 2-3 days is that ok with apple or does it have to be immediate because in the documentation they made it sound like it had to me immediate

Thanks,

Comment: It sounds like the product might be a service, in which case IAP is not permittted

Comment: that was exactly my question thanks